# Generating an APK without having an Android SDK on Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, fastlane, cicd

I’m very new to Jenkins and I’m hitting a wall right now. As the title suggests, I’m trying to set up a Jenkins job that would be able to generate an Android APK every time a commit occurs in GitLab.

My problem is that currently the Jenkins server is located on a Mac and for certain reasons I am unable to set up the Android SDK environment on the machine. Most of the guides and tutorial I’ve found on the internet requires an SDK environment to generate an APK, so I’m currently out of ideas on how to do this.

On the other hand, I was able to generate an IPA for the iOS version of the app I’m developing using Fastlane without setting up any connections to Xcode (This was done using said Mac). I would like to replicate this process on a Windows device but Fastlane doesn’t really have the best support on Windows so I’m iffy about using it. I tried looking for the Windows equivalent/alternative to Fastlane but to no avail.

So now we’re back to the title, would it be possible to generate an APK without setting up Android SDK on Jenkins?

This is a copy of https://community.jenkins.io/t/generating-an-apk-without-having-an-android-sdk/429

Comment: And how are your drive space limitations a programming problem? Why you even build locally?

Comment: Oh the drive space isn't the problem. I'm building locally right now to test out Jenkins, this is my first time using it.

Comment: You have to have the Android SDK in one way or another in order to build an APK. If, for some reasons, you can't setup the SDK on the build server, you could use a docker image that contains the SDK.

Comment: @Stephan I've no experience with dockers but at least now I have some ideas on what to look for. Thanks for the answer.